# Захват звука в системе

Tags: c, кроссплатформенность, c++

Захотелось для саморазвития научиться работать со звуком. Полез искать какие-нибудь кросс-платформенные библиотеки, которые позволяют захватывать звук и наткнулся на разные топики по этой теме, один из которых был на [RSDN](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/media/5142813.flat), где ТС советуют обратить внимание на PortAudio. 
Хорошо, скачал эту библиотеку, собрал, взял пример из их галереи примеров, собрал его и запустил - вроде всё хорошо, но в этих примерах и вообще где-либо я не смог ничего найти, позволяющего захватывать звук не с микрофона. Может плохо искал? Кто может подсказать такие примеры или примеры, позволяющие проделывать подобное с помощью других библиотек?

Comment: А откуда ещё хотите захватить звук? Или хотите захватывать то, что воспроизводиться на динамики? Или интернет радиостанции записывать?

Comment: @KoVadim, я хочу захватывать то, что идёт на динамики. Вообще любой звук.

Comment: код на с++ легко гуглиться. Я находил и даже применял этот код в продакшине.  Главное - вовремя выгребать "звуковые данные", иначе будут щелчки и выпадения.

Answer (score 2):

если тот, что воспроизводиться на динамиках, то это [WASAPI Loopback recording](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525620/Recording-audio-to-WAV-with-WASAPI-in-Windows-Stor). Если вообще любой звук - это уже к другим специалистам в совершенно других областях.